# How to implement Network Triangulation?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, triangulation, cellid

I am developing an application in android 2.2 to identify location of user by Network:

1) First:

```
location= (GsmCellLocation)tm.getCellLocation();

cellId= location.getCid();

lac= location.getLac();
```

2) Second

wonder "http://www.google.com/glm/mmap" to get latitude and longitude and range.

3) Third

I repeat this step three times to obtain information from three different cells

How can I implement the triangulation? It is possible to perform a mapping between latitude/longitude and xy co-ordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I think I've solved it... many thanks.

1. I have converted coordinates into radians.
2. I have changed the latitude/longitude (in radians) to ECEF xyz.
3. I've done some math to calculate the intersection of three circles.
4. I've re-converted the coordinates of this intersection, from ECEF to
   latitude & longitude and subsequently to degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You do [linear interpolation with the vertices of the triangle](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2007/cs3451_spring/lininter.pdf) you got.